# Mayavi cut text

Tags: python, string, text, mayavi

Is there a way to avoid mayavi to cut some characters in a text?
I'm trying to do

`t = mlab.text(0.8, 0.9, '5',  width=0.18, line_width = 1., color = (0, 0, 0))`

But I get something like`

[image: Cut text]

It looks fine if I use a text such as '25'. I also tried to use '5'.rjust(2), but with no success.

-- EDIT --
The rest of the code is this

```
from mayavi import mlab
import mayavi

# Figure specs
f = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(500, 500))

# Read a data file.
data = mlab.pipeline.open('image.vtu')

# Extract vec comp and plot
vecomp = mlab.pipeline.extract_vector_components(data)
vecomp.component = 'z-component'
surfc = mlab.pipeline.surface(vecomp, vmax=1, vmin=-1, colormap='hot')
mlab.view(elevation = 0)
t = mlab.text(0.8, 0.9, '00',  width=0.16, line_width = 1., color = (0, 0, 0))
# Save
f.scene.save('image_mayavi.png')    
mlab.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the rest of the visualization? I am not able to reproduce your problem when just plotting text.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question and put the rest of the code :) I don't know exactly if the problem is the size of the figure

Comment: I tried to just run your code snippet replacing `image.vtu` with some other stock vtu image, and it crashed with a C++ error that I didn't understand. Suffice to say, I cannot reproduce your problem with the text. The call to `mlab.text` prints out the text `00` in the renderer.

Comment: ohh, thanks for your time anyway :) Maybe it is a bug, but I'm not sure